# Why is my Sklearn LogistricRegression model predicting 100% correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have a Pandas DataFrame that is 3420 rows x 13 columns where I am trying to predict the label 'FTR' that is either a 1 or a 0. For this I am using LogisticRegression from Scikit learn. My issue is that my model is predicting 100% correctly which seems incorrect. I have the following code below:

```
dataCopy = dataCopy[['FTHG', 'FTAG', 'FTR', 'HTGS', 'ATGS', 'HTGC', 'ATGC', 'HTP', 'ATP', 'HomeTeamLP', 'AwayTeamLP', 'MW', 'HTGD', 'ATGD', 'DiffPts', 'DiffFormPts', 'DiffLP']]

X_all = dataCopy.drop(['FTR'],axis=1)
y_all = dataCopy.FTR

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_all, y_all, test_size=0.3)

LogReg = LogisticRegression()
LogReg.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = LogReg.predict(X_test)

print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

Printing out the classification report shows this:

[image]

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me why I am getting 100% because it doesn't seem right.

Comment: Sometimes it's possible with clearly separated classes and data inputs without noise. If you're not satisfied with this, show us your full pipeline including your data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the logistic regression weights? This is the `coef_` attribute in your `LogReg` logistic regression. There is a possibility that it is making predictions using one of the features much more than the others. If that's the case, is that feature reasonable to include in training?

It is hard to diagnose exactly what is going on with the information given.